# How to call React forceUpdate() on the component that is defined in JSX component tree in render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, devexpress

I have the React component with schematic code:

```
class OrderList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        //>>POI how to get reference to the Grid, that is defined in the component tree?
        //grid.forceUpdate();
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid data={this.props.orders}>
                <button onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Update</button>
            </div>  
            );
    }
}
```

`<Grid>` is some complex React component like https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/ or https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/ and its appearcance depends on some state variable. `<Grid>` is re-rendered automatically (e.g. its final, computed (by React) style is updated) if `this.props.orders` is updated. But I have `this.state.selectedOrderNo` variable which does not belong to the `this.props.orders` (of course, these are 2 different variables - array of props and scalar of state) and Grid has some styling rules that depend on `this.state.selectedOrderNo` but those styling rules are computed/rendered only when the `<Grid>` is rerendered (but this re-rendering does not happen when `this.state.selectedOrderNo` changes, because those styling rules are some deeper options than the direct parameters of the `<Grid>`) but I would like to initiate this re-rendering of the Grid when `this.state.selectedOrderNo` is changed. So, that is why I am trying to call `grid.forceUpdate()`. But the question is - **how can I get reference `grid` to the `<Grid component>`?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ref` in Grid to make it work

```
class OrderList extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleUpdate = this.handleUpdate.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    //>>POI how to get reference to the Grid, that is defined in the component tree?
    //grid.forceUpdate();
    this.grid.forceUpdate();
}


render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Grid ref={ref=>this.grid=ref} data={this.props.orders}>
            <button onClick={this.handleUpdate}>Update</button>
        </div>  
        );
}
}
```

Hope it helps